# Dynamically update UIPageViewControllerDataSource Data

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I've created simple application using Page-Based Application template. All data stored inside `var pageData = NSArray()` and in the Apple's example it initialized inside `init` method of `ModelController` class. And now I need to update pages with the data received from the server. I made method `updateDataFromServer` inside `ModelController` class where put json request to server and updating `pageData`.  If I tried to call my `updateDataFromServer` from the `init` of `ModelController` everything going wrong. From which place I should call `updateDataFromServer` and how to update `pageData` correctly? Maybe `func updateDataFromServer` should be placed in other place?

Source code: http://github.com/stillfinder/UAH-Rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your mathod inside the `RootViewController` which may subclass of `UIViewController`, you can put your method in that class, and call it from `viewDidAppear`.

As soon your method get response from the server, you can reload data source in rootview itself, and copy that array to the `modelViewController` so the `PaginationViewController` - datasource get update.

You can post your code for more help.

May this helps you.

HTH, Enjoy Coding!!